# flink insert mysql latest rows of data

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I got a recommendation table defined in mysql which has 3 columns: user_id, item_id, rank, flink will compute some recommendations and insert the results into mysql when an user clicks an item, I only want the mysql to store the recommendations triggered by the users latest click. How can I achieve that since flink mysql connector doesn's support delete? Is this kind of framework common used in such scenario if big data computing is required?

Answer (score 0):

Flink's MySQL connector does support deletes [1]. You'll have to define a primary key, then it will perform UPDATE/DELETES. If you don't supply a primary key, the connector operates in append mode.

[1] https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/connectors/table/jdbc/

Comment: Thanks a lot. I actually had read the part of doc, and my fault is that I think the primary key constraint in flink would be enough, but actually the primary key should also be constrainted in database level.